# WebCrypto API: How to decrypt a RSA encrypted message with a public key?

Tags: javascript, cryptography, rsa, webcrypto-api

I have a RSA encrypted message that can be decoded with openssl:

```
openssl rsautl -inkey cert.pem -pubin -in encrypted -out plaintext
```

How can I achieve this with the WebCrypto API? I get an error when trying the following:

```
window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
"spki",
new Uint8Array(pubKey),
{
  name: "RSA-OAEP",
  hash: {name: "SHA-256"}
},
true,
["verify"]
)
.then(function(publicKey){

  console.log(publicKey);

  window.crypto.subtle.decrypt(
    {
      name: "RSA-OAEP"
    },
    publicKey,
    new Uint8Array(encrypted)
    )
    .then(function(decrypted){
      console.log(new Uint8Array(decrypted));
    })
    .catch(function(err){
      console.error(err);
    });

})
.catch(function(err){
  throw(err);
});
```

(see https://jsfiddle.net/tz2cpze6/1/)

Comment: For starters, you can't "decrypt" anything with the public key. It would be verifying a signature, but then you would use "RSA-PSS" and not "RSA-OAEP".

Comment: Well, technically it is the same operation in RSA. Signing and verification are just different names for it when the private key is used for encryption and the public key for decryption. But back to my problem: Do I understand it right that RSA-PSS "decrypts" the signature with the public key and compares it with a hashed version of the datum that gets verified? Because in my application the hash is wrapped inside a ASN.1 structure and needs to be extracted first.

Comment: I've just looked into the [documentation](https://openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/rsautl.html). OpenSSL doesn't support PSS for signature verification, but only PKCS#1 v1.5 padding which is also distinct from OAEP. Either way, your openssl command is strange, because you're not specifying the operation: `-decrypt` or `-verify` or `-encrypt` or `-sign`

Comment: I know. But it only works without operation.

Answer (score 0):

As Artjom B. pointed out in his comment, the verify operation of the Webcrypto API does this. However, in my case PKCS#1 v1.5 was needed as the ASN.1 structure I mentioned in my comment was part of the PKCS#1 v1.5 specification.

Test signature can be generated with this OpenSSL command:

```
openssl dgst -sha1 -sign private_key.pem -out signature data
```

Verification of the created signature is possible with:

```
openssl dgst -sha1 -verify public_key.pem -signature signature data
```

This question was a result of not really understanding RFC 3477.